# Why does this formula for an integrating factor for first-order ODE work?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

The book *Shaum's Outlines: Differential Equations*, 3rd edition (page 33) provides the following condition (among others) for determining that a first-order ODE is amenable to solution via an integrating factor:

$$
M = yf(xy)
$$

and

$$
N = xg(xy)
$$

This is where the ODE is written as:

$$
M dx + N dy = 0
$$

In this case, the integrating factor is:

$$
I(x,y) = {1 \over xM - yN}
$$

I am trying to figure out why this is so, and if possible, derive an explicit expression for the function whose exact differential is ${1 \over xM - yN}(M dx + N dy)$. If this formula had a distinctive name, I could easily search the web for more information, but *Shaum's* only calls it Equation 5.10.

I found [another answer which appears to be related somehow](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653141/finding-a-general-formula-for-integrating-factor), but can't quite figure out the connection. Can anyone help?

Comment: Presumably, you intend to write $f(x, y)$ for a function of two variables, and the same for $g$?

Comment: @SammyBlack, *Shaum's* writes the formula as $f(xy)$, not $f(x,y)$. This is presumably a function of $xy$, such as $(xy)^2$, $1 + xy$, $e^{xy}$, and so on. In other words, a function whose value depends only on the product of $x$ and $y$, not their specific individual values.

Comment: Ohhhh. That's a big help. I thought that maybe it was a typo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using $M = y f(x y)$, $N = x g(x y)$, and some clever algebra we can get
\begin{multline}
\frac{Mdx + N dy}{xM-Ny} = \frac{f(xy)ydx + g(xy)xdy}{xy[f(xy) - g(x y)]} \\= \frac{[f(xy) + g(xy)][ydx + x dy]}{2xy[f(xy)-g(xy)]} + \frac{[f(xy) - g(xy)][ydx - x dy]}{2xy[f(xy)-g(xy)]}\\
= \frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{d(xy)}{2xy}\frac{f(xy) + g(xy)}{f(xy)-g(xy)} + \frac{dx}{x}-\frac{dy}{y}\right]
\end{multline}
These are all exact differentials, so the resulting integral will be
$$
\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{x}{y} + \frac{1}{2}\int_a^{xy}\frac{f(t)+g(t)}{f(t)-g(t)}\frac{dt}{t}
$$

Comment: Mouth meets floor. How did you figure that out???

Comment: @AlexD I noticed the denominator depended only on $xy$ and saw the $y dx$ and $x dy$ in the numerator, suggesting it could be written in some way as $d(xy)$. While there are a number of ways to do this, such as $f(xy)d(xy) + [g(xy) - f(xy)]x dy$, for symmetric cases like this splitting into sum and difference seems most natural.

Comment: I don't want to go too far past the original question here, but is this a "standard" test for when to use an integrating factor? Or is it just some random thing that the author of *Shaum's Notes* happened to know?

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{Mdx + N dy}{xM-Ny} = \frac{f(xy)ydx + g(xy)xdy}{xy(f(xy) - g(x y))} $$
Now use $d(xy)=xdy+ydx$:
$$ \frac{f(xy)ydx + g(xy)xdy}{xy(f(xy) - g(x y))} = \frac{f(xy)(d(xy)-xdy) + g(xy)xdy}{xy(f(xy) - g(x y))} $$
Separate into two fractions.
$$ \frac{f(xy)d(xy) }{xy(f(xy) - g(x y))}-\dfrac  {d
y}{y}=0 $$
This DE is separable.